# Implementing interface signature in different class how to know which one to use

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm new in c#, I have learned, using interface helps the code be flexible against changes in the future, for example :

it's my interface :

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Employee[] GetAll();
 }
```

and then you could have as many implementations as i like:

```
            public class EmployeeRepositoryEF: IEmployeeRepository
        {
            public Employee[] GetAll()
            {
                //here you will return employees after querying your EF DbContext
            }
        }

        public class EmployeeRepositoryXML: IEmployeeRepository
        {
            public Employee[] GetAll()
            {
                //here you will return employees after querying an XML file
            }
        }

        public class EmployeeRepositoryWCF: IEmployeeRepository
        {
            public Employee[] GetAll()
            {
                //here you will return employees after querying some remote WCF service
            }
        }
```

now in my controller:

```
            public class EmployeesController: Controller
        {
            private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;
            public EmployeesController(IEmployeeRepository repository)
            {
                _repository = repository;
            }

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var employees = _repository.GetAll();
                return View(employees);
            }   
        }
```

this GetALL() is referring to which implementation? I saw this example somewhere and still confused,  sorry if my question is stupid, but I started learning it today!

Comment: The point is that you don't need to know which one. It's usually injected for you by a [dependency injection framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: It refers to the implementation used for the object that is passed to the `EmployeesController` constructor.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes,but im using IEmployeeRepository in the controller,which is implemented getAll() in many different ways,now when i call this getAll(),i dont know which getAll() is invoked!

Comment: The MVC framework will create an instance of this controller and it will also pass in the implementation of `IEmployeeRepository`. Most likely the example you saw was using Dependency Injection; thus, some IoC was injecting the `IEmployeeRepository`. Look into dependency injection and IoC

Comment: @CodingYoshi in repository pattern examples i see in the microsoft docs,it has written anything about DI,but they implement repository pattern with interface,so,whats the benefit then?

Comment: The benefit is that every developer should be aiming to write code for at least 2 different implementation: 1. Real implementation 2. Fake implementation for unit testing. There are other benefits too but that is the most obvious. Now don't ask "what if I am not doing unit testing"? Because my answer will be "if you are not writing unit tests then you do not care about good méthodologies so therefore you can throw away interfaces too."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a question.  Which one of the 3 possible implementations would you like to use?

You can wire up any of those using your DI framework.   If you are using dotnet core then in Startup.cs you can do:

```
services.Register<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepositoryXML>();
```

Then, whenever your controller is created, IEmployeeRepository will be the XML version.

Comment: then basically i can use any kind of implementation with the same signature  ,right?if i use something like Ninject

Comment: Yes.  Just change the line in your setup and hey presto, it becomes the new one.   Of course, this only happens at startup, so you can't change it one the code is running.   If you need to do that, then you should look at the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`GetAll()` is a method defined in the interface `IEmployeeRepository`, as a result it doesn't matter and could be any one of them. This is why we use interfaces.

However the actual implementation that gets called is the one that gets injected when the `EmployeesController` gets instantiated.

If you want to know which one it's going to be, then take a look at the configuration for whichever IOC/DI framework the project is using.

Comment: so if i dont use DI,like ninject or ,...using interface is meaningless right?i mean in repository pattern,because i see in repository pattern they all using interface

Comment: Nope, the constructor could have been defined as `public EmployeesController(EmployeeRepository repository)` and DI could have still been used. Interfaces are a separate concept that regulary get used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know.

This is the whole point of abstraction: hiding implementation details behind a common contract.

In your case the abstraction is the interface `IEmployeeRepository` with a contract being `Employee[] GetAll()`. This contract promises to get all employees into an array but abstracts from *where* and *how*.

`EmployeeRepositoryEF`, `EmployeeRepositoryXML`, `EmployeeRepositoryWCF` are the implementation details which you don't have to directly know about when using them because they share the same contract (they implement `IEmployeeRepository`).